# EditText causing app crash when one is null

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have 6 EditText fields, and few checkboxes and everything is working fine when all 6 are used. Problem is when one of them is empty. I can put `if(TextUtils.isEmpty(xxx)) { - show msg` but that is not good solution for this app.

Idea is to enter first 3 Edittexts, click on button and get some values. Additional, make input in other 3 EditTexts and again press button for new calculation.

[image]

How can I get values VL1,VL2 ... (as shown on image)?

This is the code:

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET1);
    et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET2);
    et3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET3);

    et4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET4);
    et5=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET5);
    et6=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET6);

 public void Calcular(View view){
    String resultado = "";
    double VS1 = Double.parseDouble(et1.getText().toString());
    double VS2 = Double.parseDouble(et2.getText().toString());
    double VS3 = Double.parseDouble(et3.getText().toString());

  double VS4 = Double.parseDouble(et4.getText().toString());
  double VS5 = Double.parseDouble(et5.getText().toString());
  double VS6 = Double.parseDouble(et6.getText().toString());

    if (CheckB2.isChecked()){
        if (VS1 == 17) {
            double qq17 = 0.17;
            double nq17 = 14.08;
           result = " Price "+ "new" + "\n" + nq17 qq17 ;
        }
        else{

            if (VS1 == 18) {
            double qq18 = 0.18;
            double nq18 = 19.28;
           result = " Price "+ "new" + "\n" + nq18 qq18 ;
            }
...
```

Everything is working when I enter value in all 6 EditText box. This is simplified code, there are radio buttons and more data in code but it is not important for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double VS1 = 0;
double VS2 = 0;
...
if (!et1.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
  VS1 = Double.parseDouble(et1.getText().toString());
}
if (!et2.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
  VS2 = Double.parseDouble(et2.getText().toString());
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get the **null** value of any Edittext and turn it into a String such as `et1.getText().toString()` the result is an empty string like this: `""`.

According to `Double.parseDouble()` documentation, the function may throw 2 exceptions:

- NullPointerException– when the string parsed is null
- NumberFormatException– when the string parsed does not contain a parsable float

What I suspect is that `Double.parseDouble("")` is causing the crash due to an invalid value for parsing.